# Is it possible to serve a folder other than src using Vue CLI?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-cli

The reason I ask is that I am trying to serve my nyc instrumented folder when running my tests to gain code coverage.

I've been referencing Vue's documentation and I see...

```
Usage: vue-cli-service serve [options] [entry]
```

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#vue-cli-service-serve

But when I create a copy of src and run...

```
npx vue-cli-service serve src-copy/main.js
```

The app boots up with no errors, but it contains a ton of unexpected behavior across the app.

So I'm curious if I'm perhaps missing something in my command? Or is this just something that is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the unexpected behavior is that the Webpack config under the hood of Vue CLI 3 has hardcoded `src` as the name of the source directory.

So we need to change that value from `src` to (in your case) `instrumented`

How do we do this?

In your vue.config.js file we can use the `chainWebpack` method to do this declaratively. And as a bonus, we can make this conditional to whether we are in `--mode test`

```js
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
      config
        .entry('app')
        .clear()
        .add('./instrumented/main.js')
        .end();
      config.resolve.alias
        .set('@', path.join(__dirname, './instrumented'));
    }
  },
```

Now when you inspect your `webpack.txt` file, you will see...

```js
{
...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': '/home/vagrant/app/instrumented',
      ...
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
  entry: {
    app: [
      './instrumented/main.js'
    ]
  }
}
```

For a deeper dive, reference: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2019/03/18/vue-cli-3-rename-src-folder/